# Convert float64 type DataFrame to float in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a multi-indexed DataFrame wherein I used `groupby` with mean.

On checking data type of any particular value

(using `ChkVlu = df.loc['Index1'].loc['index2'].loc['requiredcolumn']`)

I get data type to be `numpy.float64`. I require the data type to native python float.

If I use `ChkVlu = float(ChkVlu)` then only one value at a time gets converted from float64 to float, however on using `df = df.astype(float)` for entire DataFrame I still get data type to be numpy.float64.

I used `df = df.astype(float, copy=False)` as well as `df = df.astype(float, copy=True)` but still getting `float64` rather than float.

Please help me in converting `float64` type DataFrame to float.

Edit1 :
Posting the code here where AnnualData.csv has index 1 and index2 as 1st 2 columns and year-month combination as next set of columns in format of 2001-01, 2001-02, 2001-03 ....... 2016-09, 2016-10, 2016-11 with numerical data in each row.
I am converting data in quarters with column names having q1, q2 and so on with mean value of each quarter.

```
 df = pd.read_csv(‘AnnualData.csv')
 df.set_index(['index1, 'index2'],inplace = True)
 def quarters(col):
  if col.endswith(("01", "02", "03")):
   final_col = col[:4] + "q1"
  elif col.endswith(("04", "05", "06")):
   final_col = col[:4] + "q2"
  elif col.endswith(("07", "08", "09")):
   final_col = col[:4] + "q3"
  else:
   final_col = col[:4] + "q4"
  return final_col  
df = df.groupby(quarters, axis = 1).mean()
ChkVlu = df.loc['index1'].loc['index2'].loc['requiredcolumn']
type(ChkVlu)
```

Comment: What is the reason for your preference on `float` over `np.float64`?

Comment: Can you display the dataframe code you have?

Comment: Pranav, try `df = df.astype(np.float)`

Comment: Hi pygo, I tried that too, but still data type remains float64. I tried pd.to_numeric(df) also but seems it works only on list or 1D array and not on 2D DataFrame

Comment: Can you update your post with the DataFrame you have to reproduce it to get an answer?

Comment: Posted the code

Comment: @Pranav,  see .. `df1 = np.float(ChkVlu)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use to_numeric which will give you a float32

or np.float32(x)

then x.item() will give you python float

Comment: @ charlie6411, what about `df1 = np.float(x)` rather `np.float32(x)`.

Comment: I think its depreciated, or will be soon

Comment: Should x be a dataframe or a single value, because the suggested method seems to work on single value while error stating 'can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar' is received if attempted on dataframe

Comment: to_numeric will work on series, remember dataframe is just a collection of series

Comment: I tried `df['requiredcolumn'] = pd.to_numeric(df['requiredcolumn'])` for one column to check the same, but still output is numpy.float64

Comment: try adding new column instead

Comment: also add downcast='float'